# Synchronised read of unsynchronised write

Tags: c++, gcc, x86

Is it possible to invoke a memory fence that will flush all cpu caches (on a multiprocessor setup) so that you can do a synchronised read of and adress that was written with a unsynchronised write (i.e. a regular MOV)?

e.g.

```
// Thread 1
data[0] = 0x67230123
std::memcpy(ptr, data, data_size);

// Thread 2
// fence
if (*ptr == 0x67230123)
  printf("Hello World")
```

I know it is a bit weird and has performance implication but I have a (probably) good reason for needing this.

Comment: This is not C. And memcpy does not guarantee atomic write. use atomics.

Comment: Does "multi process" mean multiprogramming/multitasking or multiple processors? And is this x86-specific?

Comment: @cad: multiple x86 processors.

Comment: @Olaf: Replacing memcpy with an for loop doing atomic writes would be very slow.

Comment: 1) So you prefer speed over correct code, accepting UB. 2) This is not necessarily true if only the elements are atomic, not the array itself. 3) There are other approaches, like using atomic-flags around this; I did not say you should use them for the array necessaily 4) Or use higher-level signalling 5) Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rmb() and wmb() functions, which are read and write memory barriers respectively, if we're talking about Linux.

You code for this may look the following way:

```
// Thread 1
std::memcpy(ptr, data, data_size);
wmb();

// Thread 2
smp_rmb();
if (*(ptr + 32) == 0x67230123)
    printf("Hello World")
```

wmb() forces Thread1 to write to RAM all values stored in CPU cache. And rmb() forces Thread2 to load all needed values from RAM to CPU cache to be  used in the following statements.

Comment: One should always prefer standard functions.

Comment: @Olaf: I'm fine with Linux specific functions.

Comment: @Olaf: are there some memory barriers in STL ? (yes, we can use mutex or cv, but I' talking about pure memory barrier functions)

Comment: I actually need to use `smp_wmb` and `smp_rmb` for my system.

Comment: Why not use atomics (AFAIK they are `std::atomics` in C++). And that does not solve the problem of non-atomic opdate of each element. `memcpy` does not guarantee atomic write of the elements. This relies on implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: @ronag: Such functions are often legacies and should not be used for new code. Since C(++)11 the languages themselves provide a module.

Comment: @Olaf: Because it won't work with standard atomics. Implementing an `atomic_memcpy` based on `std::atomic` would be much slower than just doing a full memory barrier i.e. `smp_mb`.

Comment: The issue is that what I want to do is not portable which C++ aims to be and I don't need to be portable. Valery's suggestion is perfect.

Comment: @ronag: So I hope to never encounter such code IRL. This is invitation to UB.

Comment: @Olaf: Best of wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional variable:

```
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable magic_event;

//thread 1
std::memcpy(ptr, data, data_size);
if(*(ptr + 32) == 0x67230123) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    magic_event.notify_one();
}

//thread 2
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> thread_lock(mutex);
    magic_event.wait(thread_lock);
    printf("Hello World");
}
```